# UCanAccess Group By

Tags: java, mysql, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

Need to learn a how work with UCanAccess where I can use a Group By with these selects.

```
 String sql =  "SELECT Route_To, BatchNo, BatchScOpr, BatchTrack, Time_Stamp,
 sum(fix_bat_sum.STOTS + fix_bat_sum.STOTR) AS Sum
 FROM fix_bat_sum GROUP BY fix_bat_sum.BatchNo";
```

I used this with a MySQL DB and it works fine but when I try to do it with a .mdb UCanAccess throws null pointer errors like this

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: expression not in aggregate or GROUP BY columns: PUBLIC.FIX_BAT_SUM.ROUTE_TO
```

Would love some help guys

Comment: You need to specify each column in group by which appear in select clause except which are used in aggregate function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to list all the non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
GROUP BY Route_To, BatchNo, BatchScOpr, BatchTrack, Time_Stamp
```

MySQL is more permissive about this than other databases, although the default changed in MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL provides a non-standard extension to GROUP BY that allows the query to be processed.

We can get MySQL to exhibit behavior similar to other relational databases by including `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in the `sql_mode`. With that, MySQL will return an error similar to the one returned by other RDBMSs.

For a explanation of the behavior, see the MySQL Reference Manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

---

An "aggregate expression" refers to the result from one of the aggregate functions, for example `MAX()`, `MIN()`, `AVG()` which operate on a set of rows to return a single value.

As a simple example of the issue:

```
foo  bar
---- ----
1    a
1    b
3    c
1    d
```

with this query

```
SELECT foo, bar FROM mytable GROUP BY foo
```

The GROUP BY clause will cause sets of rows to be "collapsed". Note that for foo=1, there are *three* possible values that could be returned for bar. Which of those values should be returned?

If we specify `MAX(bar)` or `MIN(bar)` in place of `bar`, we are specifying which value to return. Without the aggregate, the result would be indeterminate. MySQL could choose to return any one of the three values.

The standard behavior for SQL is to reject the query.